# angular hide json item inside ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json I display in my html via a service using httpclient but I would like to know if it is possible to not display everything to hide some element inside a ngFor loop.

i got this error: postArray.filter is not a function

**ts.file**

```
get() {
    this.homeService.getAll()
    .pipe(map(postArray => postArray.filter(toto => toto.hideArray)))
    .subscribe((result: Ipost[]) => {
      this.postArray = result;
    });
  }
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let t of arrayT | keyvalue">
    <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-groupe-item">{{t.key}}</li>
     <li class="list-groupe-item">{{t.value}}</li>
   </ul>
   </div>     
 </div>
</div>
```

**json**

```
{
  "toto": [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
  hideArray: [], // hide this element
"foo": [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can 'pre-process' your array received from httpclient. Check `pipe` and `map`. [docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators)

Comment: someone can help me please thank you very much

Comment: According to your json you will receive and object `{}` not `[]` array, so inside map you need to iterate over an object key, values. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to use method `filter` for the Object, but according to [Object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), this method doesn't exist there. So, you need to go with Object methods. One of them to use `rest` operator.

```
  this.homeService
    .getAll()
    .pipe(
      map((postArray) => {
        const { hideArray, ...rest } = postArray;
        return rest;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(({ foo, toto }) => {
      console.log(foo, toto);
    });
```

**UPD**: about the question from @robert

In order to remove multiple properties:

```
const removeProperties = (object, ...keys) =>
  Object.entries(object).reduce(
    (prev, [key, value]) => ({
      ...prev,
      ...(!keys.includes(key) && { [key]: value })
    }),
    {}
  );

this.homeService
  .getAll()
  .pipe(
    map((postArray: any) => {
      const propsToRemove = ['hideArray', 'toto'];
      return removeProperties(postArray, ...propsToRemove);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(obj => {
    console.log(obj); // {foo: ['foorbar', 'footix']}
  });
```

Comment: Can this list of ignored properties come from a variable? eg. `['hideArray', 'toto']` ?

Comment: thanks for the update. Works great! I guess this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, I'm a beginner, I understood that I'm using a method filter that doesn't exist so I have to create it.